# Why can't i create a table with this SQL syntax?

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE ramenrating
(
    Review # INT,
    Brand VARCHAR(30),
    Variety VARCHAR(30),
    Style VARCHAR(10),
    Country VARCHAR(20),
    Stars DECIMAL(3,2),
    Top Ten STRING,
    PRIMARY KEY (Review #)
);
```

I get this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Brand VARCHAR(30), Variety VARCHAR(30), Style VARCHAR(10), Country V' at line 3

Comment: Well - **have you checked** your MySQL manual ?? I almost bet that `Review #` is not a valid column name ....

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2):

Spaces and `#` are not allowed in identifiers (unless the identifier is escaped, which I do not recommend).  And `string` is not a type.

This works and might be what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE ramenrating( ReviewNum INT,
    Brand VARCHAR(30),
    Variety VARCHAR(30),
    Style VARCHAR(10), 
    Country VARCHAR(20), 
    Stars DECIMAL(3,2), 
    TopTen Text, 
    PRIMARY KEY (ReviewNum)
);
```

Comment: I see, thank you so much for explaining this to me!

Comment: @the-trash-panda, and also notice what Gordon did with your "top ten".  Removed the space.  I strongly suggest NOT using spaces within column names, otherwise you are `wrapping them` in tics all over the place.  Notice the CamelCasing of it too.  Helps for readability as our minds will mentally see the DistinctWords without the explicit space.